# Define died after collision particles via Particle Info node

Tags: node-editor, particles, collision

Usual "death" means Age/Lifetime ratio is 1. This is simple to define with corresponding outputs of Particle Info node, but how to deal with particles killed by collision? Maybe some math involving Velocity socket will help?